# Excel VBA - Using range variable to dynamically set range a set # of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have my code looking down a column in a specific worksheet for a certain value in a cell. If it finds that value in a cell, it uses that cell as the anchor location for the rest of the subroutine. Here is the relevant code.

```
With DailyWS
    Set DailyTable = .Range("C7:Q21")
    Set Week = .Range("F4")
End With 'DailyWS

Set rngY = BackupWS.Range("B1:B10000").Find(Replace(Week.Value, " Week", ""), lookat:=xlPart)

If rngY Is Nothing Then
    Set rngY = BackupWS.Range("B1").Offset(LastRow, 0)
End If

With BackupWS
    Set BackupTable = rngY.Offset(0, 2)
End With 'BackupWS
```

I need to take the information in the `DailyTable` range and copy it to the `BackupTable` range. As it's currently coded, it only copies one cell because `rngY` only returns one cell [for other parts of the subroutine I still need `rngY` to be this one cell].

So I need is for it to copy `DailyTable` starting at the `rngY` cell. For example, if `rngY` returns as C1, then I would need to set `BackupTable` to range C1:Q15 then perform the `.Offset(LastRow, 0)` to that.

I'm unsure how to successfully manipulate this to do that. If you need clarification, please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your request:

> if rngY returns as C1, then I would need to set BackupTable to range
>   C1:Q15 then perform the .Offset(LastRow, 0) to that.

change:

```
If rngY Is Nothing Then
    Set rngY = BackupWS.Range("B1").Offset(LastRow, 0)
End If

With BackupWS
    Set BackupTable = rngY.Offset(0, 2)
End With 'BackupWS
```

to:

```
With BackupWS
    Set rngY = .Range("B1:B10000").Find(Replace(Week.Value, " Week", ""), lookat:=xlPart)

    If rngY Is Nothing Then Set rngY = .Range("B1").Offset(LastRow, 0)

    Set BackupTable = .Range(rngY, .Range("Q15")).Offset(LastRow, 0)
End With 'BackupWS
```

but you may want to add more details to your actual goal

Comment: Perfect! I was able to make the adjustments need to the change you made to get it to work exactly how I wanted. Thanks!